# Dynamically added input fields not submitting with form in modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm encountering an issue where dynamically added input fields within a modal are not being included in the form submission data.

I have a modal that contains a form, and I'm dynamically adding input fields to this form when the user clicks an "Add" button. Each input field has a unique name attribute.

The problem is that when I submit the form, only the values of the initially loaded input fields are being included in the POST data. The dynamically added input fields are missing.

```html
<form action="print_post.php" method="post">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="repeater-<?php echo $aplId; ?>">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                    <label for="componentName" class="form-label">Component Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter component" name="componentName[]" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md mb-3">
                    <label for="componentScore" class="form-label">Score:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="componentScore[]" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md mb-3 d-flex align-items-end">
                    <button onclick="removeInput(this)" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                        <i data-feather="minus-circle" class="feather-sm fill-white"></i> Remove
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add button -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md mb-3 d-flex align-items-end">
                <button onclick="addInput(<?php echo $aplId; ?>)" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                    <i data-feather="plus-circle" class="feather-sm fill-white"></i> Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And heres the javascript included:

```js
<script>
function addInput(aplid) {
    var index = $('.repeater-' + aplid + ' .row').length;
    var html = `
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                <label for="componentName${index}" class="form-label">Component Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter component" name="componentName[${index}]" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md mb-3">
                <label for="componentScore${index}" class="form-label">Score:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="componentScore[${index}]" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md mb-3 d-flex align-items-end">
                <button onclick="removeInput(this)" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                    <i data-feather="minus-circle" class="feather-sm fill-white"></i> Remove
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
     $('.repeater-' + aplid).append(html);
}

function removeInput(button) {
    $(button).closest('.row').remove();
}
</script>
```

Heres what came out when I `print_r($_POST)`. It only takes the existing input and leaves the one in html var in js.

```php
Array ( 
    [id] => 167 
    [componentName] => Array ( 
        [0] => sample1 
    ) 
    [componentScore] => Array ( 
        [0] => 10 
    ) 
)
```

Every and each values in js should as well be submitted.

Comment: Where's the `<form>`?

Comment: So when you look in your browser "Network" developer tab, when you do whatever you do to submit the form, you should be able to see the outgoing HTTP request and look at the parameters that are being sent.

Comment: @Pointy, I can still only see the initial input being sent but not the one I added using addInput().

Comment: What is the `${index}` variable represents?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sjkxqy8c/ appears to submit the data correctly. But, I had to insert static values in those parts, where you are outputting stuff dynamically via PHP - so it is currently impossible for us to say, if my example reproduces your situation correctly. If you can't figure it out on your own, then please show us a _static_ version of the problem, that has all PHP code replaced with its actual output.

Comment: How does [tag:php] handle missing indexes?   eg `<input name='val[0]'` `<input name='val[3]'`   In [tag:asp.net-mvc] this will only receive the first value.   Your code will generate gaps in the indices.

Comment: TBH I would expect the `<form>` to be *inside* the `modal-body`  - so it could depend on how your modals work.

Comment: @CBroe, i see, well in my case the modal was in a loop(row of table). maybe thats the prob?

Comment: @freedomn-m, i had to put the tag outside since them buttons was in `modal-footer`

Comment: Add row, adds as [1], add row, adds as [2], delete row [1], add row, adds as [2] again - you now have two with [2] - only one will be POST'd

Comment: Similarly, your original (in the HTML) inputs have `name=componentName[]` but subsequent (dynamic) inputs have `name=componentName[123]` - I suspect this is what's causing the POST issue.  Try setting the html name `as `componentName[0]` or the dynamic inputs as `name=componentName[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser generally gathers form elements that exist in the DOM at **at the time of submission.** Having said this, when you submit, the *dynamically* added elements using `append()` may not be included as they might be appended **after** the initial form creation.

This behaviour potentially results in lost input values when you expect them in `$_POST`. You can resolve this issue by triggering form submission **after** appending elements. Considering the following steps

1. Access the form in `javascript` by `ID` :

```
<form id="printPost" method="POST" action="">
   //form inputs
</form>

<script>
 const form = document.getElementById("printPost");
</script>
```

2. Add new elements dynamically like you are doing using your `function addInput(aplid)`, **but** instead of appending it like `$('.repeater-' + aplid).append(html);`, append it to the form object like `form.append(html)`. You should see the items added to your `formdata` and it should reflect in your network call after you submit.

You can also consider submitting the data using `ajax` directly to your php file if you don't want to rely on form submission.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. it work but I can only append it to form, which kind of destroy the interface. I tried to append to something else; new div, but it wouldnt send the data.

Comment: They don't need to be direct decedents of `<form>`.  This is a red-herring.

Comment: @freedomn-m - Please propose the alternate solution which would work. Would love to learn from you.